Implementation of trust model for Rsu to Rsu communication in VANETs in OMNET5

I am trying to implement a trust model for RSU to RSU communication in OMNET. I have added a certain number of RSUs to the network. Where exactly should the trust model be implemented? Also, how can I implement one?

And if I have a bunch of calculations regarding the trust score and finding the gobal trust in the trust model how exactly should it be implemented in OMNET?


Folder structure screenshot 1
Folder structure screenshot 2
Folder structure screenshot 3
These are screen shots of the folder structure of Veins in OMNET. I want to know in which file exactly the trust model can be implemented and how?
Any code reference will be a real help.
